# Deleting a Rails Post via Bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

I might just not be thinking clearly, but instead of using a data-confirm to delete a Rails posts, I'd rather delete it via a modal (im using bootstrap). So when you click the delete the post, the modal opens and you can delete it from there. Does anyone have a good solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What about putting a delete button in a modal? Maybe something like this (don't know you exact situation so this code is just a general idea),

```
<!-- Delete Button -->
<%= link_to('Delete Post', '#', class: 'btn', :'data-toggle' => 'modal', :'data-target' => '#myModal') %>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <%= link_to("Confirm Delete", post, method: :delete, class: 'btn') %>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yea I'm using that on the Post's show page, unfortunately it won't work on the index page where you list more than one Post. Thanks for the help @user

Comment: If you update your question with some code from your index page, maybe I can help, either way, good luck!